# Changing the background-color of a jumbotron from bootstrap in django

Tags: css, django

I am very new to web development and Django. I am following a tutorial called "Try Django 1.8".

In this code I am supposed to change the background-color of jumbotron to #155A1E.

If I press shift + refresh in google chrome, the color shows up then it changes back to gray. When I inspect the code in google chrome, I can see in the styles tab that the background-color in the .jumbotron{} has a strike-through. Also there is another verion of .jumbotron{} in the styles tab that has a background-color and has a check. If I uncheck the box, the color gets fixed.

[image]

How can I fix this in Django?

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


{% block head_title %}Welcome | {{ block.super}}{% endblock %}

<style>
{% block style %}
    .jumbotron {
        background-color: #155A1E;
    }
{% endblock %}
</style>


{% block jumbotron %}

    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class='container'>
            <div class="row">
                <div class='col-sm-6'>
                    <h1>Try Django 1.8</h1>
                    <p>Some text here!!! This text should be long so that we can test the columns in the webpage. So here we go. We are trying to make this line as long as possible.</p>
                    <p>
                      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="" role="button">Join us &raquo;</a>
                    </p>

                </div>

                <div class='col-sm-6' style="background-color:black;height:300px">


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}




{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="row">


    </div>


  <div class="col-xs-3 pull-right">
        <p class='lead text-align-center'>{{ title}}</p>

        <!--{{ user }}-->

        <!--&lt;!&ndash;{{ request.user }}&ndash;&gt;-->

        <!--abc is = {{ abc }}-->

        <form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}

            {{ form|crispy }}

            <input class='btn btn-primary' type="submit" value="Signup" />
        </form>
  </div>

    <div class='col-sm-3'>
        <p class='lead text-align-center'>Built with Django &amp; Bootstrap</p>
    </div>

    <div class='col-sm-3'>
        <p class='lead text-align-center'>created for starters of all kinds.</p>
    </div>

    <div class='col-sm-3'>
        <p class='lead text-align-center'>Always open source.</p>
    </div>

 </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Where are you adding bootstrap.min.css?

Answer (score 1):

You can add do important to your css attribute.

Just like that:

```
.jumbotron {
    background-color: #155A1E!important;
}
```

It will be taken instead of the default one

Answer (score 1):

It may be very late to answer the question but could help someone who is doing the tutorial now as myself.
Problem is your style should come under the

```
{% block jumbotron %}
```

otherwise its never been executed.

Here it is

```
 {% block jumbotron %}
    <style>
    {% block style %}
    .jumbotron {
        background-color : #1e78d2 !important;
    }
    {% endblock %}
    </style>

<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">....... {% endblock %}
```

Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Makesure source of bootstrap is before your style source, and example:

```
<link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
<link href="{% static 'css/your_style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
```